# Openssl version error on Mac 10.11.5 to install composer

Tags: macos, openssl, composer-php, homebrew, cakephp-3.0

I got stack about 6 hours to install composer. Searched & tried all possible ways but couldn't fix. Can anyone please help me?

[image]

Main two of the tried links are below-

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/126830/how-to-upgrade-openssl-in-os-x
- https://superuser.com/questions/324616/how-should-i-set-the-path-variable-on-my-mac-so-the-hombrew-installed-tools-are

Updates

---

I've used the following commands-

> brew update
>
> brew install openssl
>
> brew link --force openssl
>
> openssl version -a
>
> which openssl

And put /usr/local/bin above /usr/bin as follows-

1. On OS X, open Terminal
2. Type the command: sudo vi /etc/paths
3. Enter your password if you're asked for it
4. You will see a list of paths.
5. Edit them so that /usr/local/bin path is entered above the /usr/bin
   path
6. Save and quit and Restart Terminal

After following these steps I'm trying to install composer by the command

> curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php

but it showing the following message-

> The OpenSSL library (0.9.8y) used by PHP does not support TLSv1.2 or TLSv1.1.
>
> If possible you should upgrade OpenSSL to version 1.0.1 or above.

Comment: But what happens when you follow the solutions from these 2 links? Are they upgrading openssl fine or what?

Comment: If you can provide more information, like the exact steps to produce a particular failure, then we may be able to help you further. Also, please don't post pictures with error messages. The error message cannot be indexed.

Comment: I've added the details as you said.

Comment: @jaw You've marked it as duplicate. But, I've shared other links on my question and those didn't solve my problem. And maybe I've got my answer-
https://coreyolson.com/2016/02/14/php-curl-fails-on-cloudflare-or-sslv3-sites-using-mamp-3-5-due-to-old-openssl-version/